An error occurred while parsing EntityName. C#
Error message parsing entityname
Error Image
i have problem to parsing xml file with following code below
  for (int index = 0; index <= elementsByTagName.Count - 1; ++index)
        {
          this.DGVBond.Rows.Add();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bcode"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bname"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bemitent_code"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bdate_maturity"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bratings"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["bcreated_date"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText.Trim();
          this.DGVBond.Rows[index].Cells["brevised_date"].Value = (object)elementsByTagName[index].ChildNodes.Item(7).InnerText.Trim();
        }

i did try to escape & character
private string EscapeXmlCharacters(string input)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
         return input;

     return input
         .Replace("&", "&amp;")
         .Replace("<", "&lt;")
         .Replace(">", "&gt;")
         .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
         .Replace("'", "&apos;");
 }

and change to this

    for (int num = 0; num <= elementsByTagName.Count - 1; num++)
    {
        DGVBond.Rows.Add();
        
        var codeBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("code_bonds")?.InnerText ??string.Empty;
        var nameBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("name_bonds")?.InnerText ??string.Empty;
        var emitentCodeBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("emitent_code_bonds")?.InnerText ?? string.Empty;
        var dateMaturityBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("date_maturity_bonds")?.InnerText ?? string.Empty;
        var ratingsBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("ratings_bonds")?.InnerText ?? string.Empty;
        var createdDate = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("created_date")?.InnerText ?? string.Empty;
        var revisedDate = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("revised_date")?.InnerText ?? string.Empty;

       
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bcode"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(codeBonds);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bname"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(nameBonds);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bemitent_code"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(emitentCodeBonds);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bdate_maturity"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(dateMaturityBonds);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bratings"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(ratingsBonds);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["bcreated_date"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(createdDate);
        DGVBond.Rows[num].Cells["brevised_date"].Value = EscapeXmlCharacters(revisedDate);
    }

the error pointed to
var nameBonds = elementsByTagName[num].SelectSingleNode("name_bonds")?.InnerText ??string.Empty;

its still showing same error, every thread in forum says that & to replace became `& amp;` but still didn't works at all.
please help thanks

Did the xml have any escape characters containing the ampersand before you executed .Replace("&", "&")?  You would of gotten as result of fixing "<"  with "&lt;"
